# Detect if vertex is inside a list of points (cube)

Tags: c++, math, 3d

I want to find if a vertex is inside of a cube in a C++ program.

Take this example, I want to find all vertices of the torus that lie inside of the cube.

[Image](http://puu.sh/dnvZt/751c4e089a.jpg)
[image]

How would I go on doing this, knowing that my cube is just a list of points to start with (I'm parsing an .obj file)

For example, my cube vertices:

```
v  -56.269790649414 -100.226547241211 -29.616094589233
v  3.730209350586 -100.226547241211 -29.616094589233
v  -56.269790649414 -40.226547241211 -29.616094589233
v  3.730209350586 -40.226547241211 -29.616094589233
v  -56.269790649414 -100.226547241211 30.383905410767
v  3.730209350586 -100.226547241211 30.383905410767
v  -56.269790649414 -40.226547241211 30.383905410767
v  3.730209350586 -40.226547241211 30.383905410767
```

What are the best practices/algorithms to achieve this (raycasting?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your cube is axis-parallel, so it is sufficient to check whether the vertex to test lies in the intersection of the slice of the parellel side planes. To put it differently, an axis-parallel cube is its own bounding box. Let

```
x_max = maximum x-coordinate of the cube
x_min = minimum x-coordinate of the cube
y_max = maximum y-coordinate of the cube
y_min = minimum y-coordinate of the cube
z_max = maximum z-coordinate of the cube
Z_min = minimum z-coordinate of the cube
```

then a point `(x,y,z)` is contained in the cube if and only if

```
x_min <= x <= x_max && y_min <= y <= y_max && z_min <= z <= Z_max
```

However things are more complicated if the cube is actually not axis-parallel.

Comment: Thanks! Can you point me to some of the things to do when my cube isn't axis-parallel? I might encounter those cases too.

Comment: I would try the following approach. From the coordinates of the point, try to get a half-space representation of the cube, i.e. a system of 6 inequalities, each expressing the normal of the corresponding face and its shortest distance from the origin. The check whether the point `(x,y,z)´ satisfies all of the inequalities. However, it must be known which vertices constitute which face.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary mesh (not just the cube), you can generate a ray from the point you want to test and see how many times the ray intersects with your mesh. For even number of intersections (including zero) => point is outside, for odd number of intersections => point is inside. But it could be faster if you can bring your cube to origin and align it along the axes. Then it's just a matter or three ifs.

Comment: Also a good answer; implementational difficulty depends a bit on the internal representation of the cube. Only the vertices might not be optimal.